# Greedy navigation in Angular

Tags: javascript, navigation, event-listener, greedy

I'm new to angular and I'd like to use a greedy navigation as the link below

https://codepen.io/lukejacksonn/pen/PwmwWV

but the problem is that I've been warned not to use document.queryselector(".myElement") for attaching JS eventListeners directly to any DOM element in angular.

Which would be the best way in angular to manage changes in DOM element properties like div's width or any other property of a particular element?

```
    <nav class='greedy-nav'>
<button><div class="hamburger"></div></button>
  <ul class='visible-links'>
    <li><a target="_blank" href='https://github.com/lukejacksonn/GreedyNav'>Greedy</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>that</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>handles</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>overflowing</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>elements</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>effortlessly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='hidden-links hidden'></ul>
</nav>



@color-1: #ff9800;
@color-2: #f57c00;
@color-3: #ef6c00;

body {
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #ff9800;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  max-width: 50ex;
}

p.large {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.greedy-nav {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #fff;

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: @color-1;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
      color: @color-3;
    }
  }

  button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: @color-2;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
      background-color: @color-3;
    }

    &::after {
      content: attr(count);
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      left: -16px;
      top: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: @color-3;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 28px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    &:hover::after {
      transform: scale(1.075);
    }
  }

  .hamburger {
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: auto;

    &:before, 
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 32px;
      height: 4px;
      background: #fff;
    }

    &:before {
      top: -8px;
    }

    &:after {
      bottom: -8px;
    }
  }

  .visible-links {
    display: inline-table;

    li {
      display: table-cell;
      border-left: 1px solid @color-1;
    }
  }

  .hidden-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100%;

    li {
      display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid @color-2;
    }
  }

  .visible-links li:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    a { color: @color-1 !important; }
  }

  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}




var $nav = $('.greedy-nav');
var $btn = $('.greedy-nav button');
var $vlinks = $('.greedy-nav .visible-links');
var $hlinks = $('.greedy-nav .hidden-links');

var breaks = [];

function updateNav() {

  var availableSpace = $btn.hasClass('hidden') ? $nav.width() : $nav.width() - $btn.width() - 30;

  // The visible list is overflowing the nav
  if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {

    // Record the width of the list
    breaks.push($vlinks.width());

    // Move item to the hidden list
    $vlinks.children().last().prependTo($hlinks);

    // Show the dropdown btn
    if($btn.hasClass('hidden')) {
      $btn.removeClass('hidden');
    }

  // The visible list is not overflowing
  } else {

    // There is space for another item in the nav
    if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1]) {

      // Move the item to the visible list
      $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
      breaks.pop();
    }

    // Hide the dropdown btn if hidden list is empty
    if(breaks.length < 1) {
      $btn.addClass('hidden');
      $hlinks.addClass('hidden');
    }
  }

  // Keep counter updated
  $btn.attr("count", breaks.length);

  // Recur if the visible list is still overflowing the nav
  if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
    updateNav();
  }

}

// Window listeners

$(window).resize(function() {
    updateNav();
});

$btn.on('click', function() {
  $hlinks.toggleClass('hidden');
});

updateNav();
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as angular? I don't see a single line of angular in here. If you are trying to make the above code work in angular, I strongly suggest you revisit the angular tutorials and learn how to use angular the correct way. The above code looks like a jQuery application to me. If you're going to use angular, get jQuery out of your project. They do not coexist.

Comment: You are right, I don't know Angular, thats why I'm asking for advice here. I'm not trying to use jquery within angular, but to make a greedy nav in it. do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I have no idea what a "greedy nav" is. I would start with some angular tutorials to figure out if you even want to use it in the first place. Angular is an animal of its own so if you're new to frontend/javascript, you might want to stick with a vanilla/jquery setup until you're more comfortable. Angular is a completely different thought process when writing web apps.

Comment: @christian35620 Were you able to achieve it?